# Which STL container could grow in both directions?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Given an iterator to the beginning, and one past the end, is there a container in STL that would allow me to dynamically and simultaneously fill in data from both ends, without having to allocate the maximum size previously? As per my understanding, I could use a template like vector or string, which can be dynamically grown in the forward direction using say the push_back() method. Or I could use a template like array with predetermined size, which can be accessed in both forward and reverse directions simultaneously to fill in data.

What I am looking for is a template that would allow me the flexibility of a dynamically growing container, like vector, while enabling data population from either end, like array. In the case of the array, there is a predetermined gap between the begin and end iterators (due to the fixed size); I would want this gap to grow dynamically as I fill in the data simultaneously from either end, in the case of the dynamic container template.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Thanks

Vinod

Comment: deque container.

Comment: Have you tried deque?

Answer (score 6):

This sounds exactly what the [std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) (double ended queue) was created for:

> **Quoting cppreference.com**
>
> std::deque (double-ended queue) is an indexed sequence container that allows fast insertion and deletion at both its beginning and its end. In addition, insertion and deletion at either end of a deque never invalidates pointers or references to the rest of the elements.

Its interface is similar to a `std::vector` but efficiently allows additions to the front and back:

```
std::deque<int> dq;

dq.push_back(5);
dq.push_front(9);

std::cout << dq[0] << '\n';
std::cout << dq[1] << '\n';
```

**Output:**

```
9
5
```